# Sensors used on a blade

Tags: experimental-aircraft, blade, sensors, measurement, engineering

How to measure the strain, temperature and rotational dynamics on a running engine fan blade? How can you do the experiment?

Comment: There are devices like strain gauges, temperature sensors, and accelerometers that are all quite small and can be attached to almost anything.  You will also need something to read those devices like a microcontroller, also quite small today.  You'll also need some way to power it, a small battery comes to mind.  I'd use a wireless connection of some sort as a wired connection to a rotating blade is tricky.

Comment: Welcome to stack, this video on the FlightChops channel touches on that issue briefly. They don't go much into detail because its likely considered proprietary methods for doing business competitively. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5t6VefAyRo